# issues with funnel of highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-highcharts

I'm trying to create a funnel chart using highcharts-react-official but I get an error that says:

****Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'noop' of undefined**

it occurs in funnel.js inside highchart's modules. and makes browers stuck in debugger mode. Any help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance

this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import TextCountComp from '../../../../shared/components/textCount/TextCountComp';
import useStyles from './ChartAnalyticsCompStyle';
import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import funnel from "highcharts/modules/funnel.js";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

funnel(Highcharts);


const options =  {
  series: [
    {
      type: "funnel",
      data: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  ]
}

const ChartAnalyticsComp = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={2} className={classes.grid}>
        <TextCountComp className={classes.box} align="center" headText="Total" value="$0" />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs>
        {/* chart goes here */}
        Chart
        <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid container item xs direction="column">
        {/* texts goes here just use <Typography> component for each line of text */}
        <Typography>Text 1</Typography>
        <Typography>Text 2</Typography>
        ....
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default ChartAnalyticsComp;
```

this is the TextCountComp that is used above.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Typography, TypographyTypeMap } from '@material-ui/core';

interface PropType {
  headText: string;
  value: string | number;
  color?: TypographyTypeMap['props']['color'];
  align?: TypographyTypeMap['props']['align'];
  border?: boolean;
  className?: string;
}

const TextCountComp = (
  {
    headText, value, color, border, align, className,
  }: PropType,
) => (
    <Box border={+border!} className={className}>
    <Typography variant="body1" color={color}>{headText}</Typography>
    <Typography align={align} variant="body1" color="secondary">{value}</Typography>
  </Box>
);

TextCountComp.defaultProps = {
  color: 'primary',
  border: true,
  align: 'center',
  className: undefined,
};

export default TextCountComp;
```

Comment: can you share your TextCountComp because without it your code seems to work fine 
[codeBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-surf-5log7?file=/src/graph.js:359-377)

Comment: @antoineso I have attached the component. please check it.
Thanks for replying.